# keeping search and filter dropdown on same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Im working on a section on a webpage, using bootstrap but cant keep filter on same line. Ive tried a few ways, currently trying columns, tried divs inline, still not lining up correctly.

```html
div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="rev-search" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right:.5em;" >
        <input type="text" style="width: 80%;" id="rev-search" placeholder="Search" autofocus="" />
        <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
     <div class="dropdown pull-right">
       <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="float: right;" type="button" id="group_filter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo $text_filter_group;?><span class="caret"></span></button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="group_filter">
       <?php
        foreach ($customer_groups as $group){
         echo '<li><a href="'.$groupSearch.'&amp;filter_customer_group_id='.$group['order_id'].'">'.$group['name'].'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because there is padding on the col-lg-10 and col-lg-2. Add this to your css to remove the padding which is pushing your drop down to the next row.

```
.col-lg-10, .col-lg-2 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the Bootstrap documentation, please use lg (for larger desktops).

Also try wrapping your row in a fluid container.

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">

    </div>
  </div>
```